# General term formula of series 1/1 + 1/2 + 1/3 ... +1/n

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, recurrence-relations, recreational-mathematics

any hint how to resolve

$$f(n) = \frac 11 + \frac 12 +\frac 13 + \dots + \frac 1n$$

What I'm trying to do is to find connection between

$$f(n),\,f(n+1)$$
different of

$$f(n+1) = f(n)+\frac 1{n+1}$$

So I could create system.

Comment: Do you know the notation with the $\sum$ sign?

Comment: This sum is called $H_n$ the $n$th"harmonic number" and has no known closed form.

Comment: Hmm, I don't think i know it. coffe I will check thank you for the suggestion

Comment: @coffeemath Debatable: you can write
$$H_n=\frac{S_{n+1}^2}{n!}$$
Where $S$ denotes Stirling numbers of the first kind. But it may not be considered a "closed form", since Stirling numbers are not much more easy than harmonic numbers.

Comment: Titi Kokov: A Wikipedia reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number

Comment: @coffeemath  See my answer.

Comment: @LorenoHeer You can see my answer.

Answer (score 5):

$$\Gamma(x+1)=x\Gamma(x)$$
$$\Gamma'(x+1)=\Gamma(x)+x\Gamma'(x)$$
$$\frac{1}{x}=\frac{\Gamma'(x+1)}{x\Gamma(x)}-\frac{\Gamma'(x)}{\Gamma(x)}=\frac{\Gamma'(x+1)}{\Gamma(x+1)}-\frac{\Gamma'(x)}{\Gamma(x)}$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{i}=\frac{\Gamma'(n+1)}{n!}-\Gamma'(1)=\frac{\Gamma'(n+1)}{n!}+\gamma$$
where $\gamma$ is the Euler constant.

Comment: Aw man, such an old question.  I hope you find my new answer quite enjoyable.  (also, your answer extends to higher derivatives via the polygamma function)

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Awesome, you give a perturbative solution.

Answer (score 4):

I can give you a good approximation if you would prefer:

$$\ln(n+1)\le\sum_{i=1}^n\frac1i\le\ln(n)+1$$

This is a rather tight upper limit and lower limit you can use to approximate your answer.

One could also note that

$$\sum_{i=1}^n\frac1i=\int_0^1\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}x^i\ dx=\int_0^1\frac{1-x^n}{1-x}\ dx$$

We also have the Euler-Maclaurin expansion:

$$\sum_{i=1}^n\frac1i=\ln(n)+\gamma+\frac1n-\frac1{4n^2}+\mathcal O(n^{-4})$$

Comment: You can see my answer

Answer (score 1):

Since the comments above the solution of the problem

> $f(n) = 1/1 + 1/2 +1/3 + ... + 1/n$

is using Harmonics Numbers:

> $f(n)=H_n$ the $n$-th [harmonic number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number).

Comment: You can see my answer

Answer (score 0):

This is the harmonic series. It has no closed-form solution to the extent of my knowledge. In the limit, it is divergent (meaning that it sums to infinity). I can't think of any good way to recast the equation over a common denominator (which would be $n!$).

Comment: well i worte the answer myself if someone would need it in the future.

Comment: Regarding your last sentence, there is (see my comment above).

Comment: edited my answer

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut  You can see my answer

Comment: @FundThmCalculus You can see my answer

Comment: " I can't think of any good way to recast the equation over a common denominator (which would be n!)."  Well, ask a silly question and ....  If we define $\overline {kn} = \frac {n!}k$ then we get $\sum \frac 1k = \frac {1}{n!} \sum \overline {kn}$, which doesn't help us one whit....(I guess that is what you meant by "good").

Comment: @fleablood You can see my answer.